# curl send JSON data not working using C++

Tags: c++, curl

I need to send an ID (JSON data) using cUrl library and it's not working.

This is the command:

```sh
curl --request POST \
  --url https://pos-api.ifood.com.br/v1.0/events/acknowledgment \
  --header 'Authorization: bearer {acess_token}' \
  --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '[{"id":"Event_id1"},{"id":"Event_id2"},{"id":"Event_id3"},{"id":"Event_id4"}]'
```

I have this function. The input parameters are:
valid token and str (JSON Data) as `[{"id":"b7e17af5-fd21-4690-b908-71d489d53355"}]`.

Using this JSON input data and a valid token there is no error at command line, but when I tried to use with my C++ function, there is an error 400 (shown at the end).

```
int iFood_Acknowledgment(QString str, QString token) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    QString autorizacao;

    autorizacao=QString("Authorization: bearer %1").arg(token);

      /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
      curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

      /* get a curl handle */
      curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl) {
          qDebug() << "autorizacao " << autorizacao.toLocal8Bit().constData() << autorizacao.toUtf8();
          qDebug() << "iFood_Acknowledgment executando..." << qPrintable(str);

        /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
           just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
           data. */
          struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;

          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://pos-api.ifood.com.br/v1.0/events/acknowledgment");
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, qPrintable(str));
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, str.size());
          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
   //       curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

          headers = curl_slist_append(headers, qPrintable(autorizacao));
          headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Cache-Control: no-cache");
          headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8");
       //   headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "charsets: utf-8");

          curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if(res != CURLE_OK){
          qDebug() << "iFood_Acknowledgment falhou...";
          fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                  curl_easy_strerror(res));
        }

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
        curl_slist_free_all(headers);

        return 1;

      }
      curl_global_cleanup();
      return 0;
}
```

This function returns with an error code 400:

```
{"timestamp":"2018-04-28T01:10:32.681+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"Bad Request","path":"/events/acknowledgment"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The data for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` must outlive the request. But `qPrintable` returns a pointer that becomes invalid at the semicolon. You are sending random garbage to the server. One solution might be to use `CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS` instead.

Comment: is iFood_Acknowledgment() guaranteed to only be called once per program execution? because curl_global_init is only supposed to be called once.

Comment: my best guess is, qPrintable(str)  isn't actually returning a valid json... but what is it returning?

Comment: @eyllanesc reading the code, it's obviously c++ (you don't see `qDebug() << "autorizacao " << ~~` in C code)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody.

I´m using Qt ( it´s explain QString and qDebug ).

The problem was the output from qPrintable to (char *)

The qPrintable output showed to me in qDebug seems ok, but isn´t!

I put this:
        char *s;

```
    s=(char *)malloc(str.length());
    QByteArray ba=str.toLatin1();  // str is my json input data
    strcpy(s,ba.data());
```

And

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, s);
```

Now this function is ok.

Thank you all!